# Is it possible to use audience targeting on form elements in NewForm.aspx?

Tags: audience-targeting

Is it possible to use audience targeting on Newform.aspx, such that a particular audience may only see some of the form fields?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot audience target input fields.  You will have to customize the form to achieve this functionality.  If this is a possibility for you, I can update my answer with some examples, if you'd like.